# My EC2 instance has a Public IP but don't have a Public DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created a new VPC called **testglobal** with 2 subnets: **opennet, closednet**

So I created EC2 instances on those subnets and now I can't ping them.

**In EC2 panel it shows the Public IP but don't shows Public DNS.**

They are all associated to ElasticIPs and added to a group with All Traffic IN/OUT.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I suspect it can be an issue with route tables, but I don't know exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 instances in your public subnet (what you've called **opennet**) will have a public DNS and a public IP address. You will only be able to ping them if they are in a security group that allows ICMP echo requests from your client-side IP address.

Instances in your private subnet (**closednet**) will not have public IP addresses or public DNS names. They will only have private addresses within the range of your subnets. That is the intent of a private subnet - to not allow direct public Internet traffic. Access systems in the private subnets only from the instance in public subnets, or alternatively via VPN.

More specific advice would require further information, like screenshots of the instance, subnet, route table and security group details.